# ページ遷移時のデータの受け渡し について

Tags: monaca

お世話になっております。

● キーワードを１ページ目で入力し、２ページ目に表示する方法
が知りたいです。

```
<script>
  function mHozon() {
  key = $("#key").val();
  document.getElementById("keyword").innerText = key;
</script>
```

スクリプトの部分でキーワードを取得し、書き換えたいです。

```
<body>
  <!-- Top Page -->
  <div data-role="page" id="TopPage">
  <header data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-theme="c">
  <h1>Hozon Page1</h1>
  </header>
  <section data-role="content">
  <h1>キーワード</h1>
    <input type="text" id="key">
    <br>
    <a href="#MainPage" id="button" onclick="mHozon" data-role="button" data-inline="false" data-theme="b">O.K.</a>
  </section>
  </div>

  <!-- Main Page -->
  <div data-role="page" id="MainPage">
  <header data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-theme="c">
  <h1>Hozon Page2</h1>
  </header>
  <section data-role="content">
  <h1>キーワード</h1>
  <p id="keyword" >ここに表示</p>
  </section>
  </div>
</body>
```

ご指摘 よろしくお願いします。

【補足】
上記の方法に**こだわりません**。
１ページ目に入力されたキーワードが、２ページ目に渡すことができれば それで良いのです。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`function`の終わり`}`がありません。

```
<script>
    function mHozon() {
        key = $("#key").val();
        document.getElementById("keyword").innerText = key;
    }
</script>
```

`mHozon`に`()`がありません。

```
<a href="#MainPage" id="button" onclick="mHozon()" data-role="button" data-inline="false" data-theme="b">O.K.</a>
```

Comment: ご指摘ありがとうございます。
これで表示することは出来るのですが、ここで取得した値を保存しておき、アプリケーションを再起動した時に、その値を呼び出すことは可能でしょうか？
もし可能なら、どのようにするのか教えて頂けないでしょうか。
引き続き 宜しくお願いします。

Comment: localStorageで保存できます。 [localStorageを使用して端末にデータを保存する](http://blog.asial.co.jp/939)

Comment: ご回答頂き、ありがとうございます。